# Is it safe to still use an iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, security

I've received an iPhone 4 for free and I would like to use it. Last iOS version available is iOS 7.1.2 released on June 30, 2014 which is now unsupported.

My questions are: Is there some known security vulnerabilities on iOS 7.1.2 and is there known hardening techniques available.

This phone was almost not used and the hardware including the battery is almost new. It would be a shame to use it only as a clock watch.

Comment: It depends on the kind of things you would want to use the phone for. Using it simply as a cellular device shouldn't be an issue. Also, you'll need to factor in the fact you will most likely not be able to install most of the apps currently available on the App Store.

Comment: If you do not use Internet on it and only as Cell Phone , it is perfectly safe. However, consider upgrading it to newer iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full list of security protection systems is available on Apples website [here.](https://support.apple.com/HT202816)

It contains the impact of the issue and what is fixed. Ultimately, it’s up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Not safe to use it anymore.  iOS is at v.12.1 at the present time. 
So all flaws from iOS 7 to iOS 12 are open for your device. 
You can still use it as a backup device.